# Powershell dont seem to work correctly on 64Bit but works fine on 32Bit and the exe works on both bit

Tags: powershell, script, 32-vs-64-bit

Hi i have a Powershell script that runs just after windows fresh install. The script auto install Microsoft Office Starter 2010

This work correctly on 32Bit without any problem. But when i run on 64Bit i pops up with error saying Office cannot be install tr again. 
I have tested this EXE on 32Bit and 64Bit and it works correctly with no problems but when trying it on the script the errors happen.

```
#This checks the Internet for the Correct time and Date
Set-Date (Get-Date)

# This starts the office install which doesnt need to be a part of the other command
$p = New-Object System.Diagnostics.Process
$pinfo = New-Object System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo("C:\Install_File\Office.exe","");
$p.StartInfo = $pinfo;
$p.Start();
$p.WaitForExit();
Write-Host "end of ps1" + (Get-Date).DateTime
```

Comment: Have you identified which line in the script is causing the problems?  I presume it's either when you check the time and date or when you attempt to start the installer itself.  Are you able to start any installers on the 64-bit installation?

Comment: hi its when it starts the the installer itself

Comment: You didn't answer my question.  Please edit your question and provide the required clarification.